# Select polyline features and see total length in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, summarizing

I have a layer of polylines representing sewer mains. I want to break the layer down into groups of approximately the same length and area.

Is there a way I can select multiple features in ArcMap and see the total length.  That way I can add or subtract until I get the selection approximately correct.  There are over 3000 lines covering 127km, and I want to break it down into say 10 packages of approximate same total length and in the same general area.  I have a range of similar assets that I want to repeat the process on.

I have seen the summary statistics tool that can do this for the full layer.  However there doesn't seem to be an option to do it for the selection only like QGIS often has.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @ahmadhanb](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382268/select-polyline-features-and-see-total-length-in-arcmap/390876#comment625298_382268):

> Select the lines, then switch to selection in the attribute table, and
> finally right-click the length field and view `Statistics`. You can
> refer to this help:
> https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/viewing-statistics-for-a-table.htm